# Tapestry pagelink with dynamic css class

Tags: css, tapestry

I try set a dynamic css class value for a pagelink in a simple custom component and can't find any way.

My component ...

```
<!-- my component template 'testLink' -->
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <!-- maybe I can set here something dynamic like that ...
        <t:pagelink page="mytest" t:id="myLink" class="${myDynCss}">

        ... but in this case I need to pass the parameter what link is handled
    -->
    <t:pagelink page="mytest" t:id="myLink">
        I want dynamic css class            
    </t:pagelink>
</html>
```

The component java code ...

```
public class TestLink {
    @Parameter(required=true)
    private int activeId;

    @Component
    PageLink myLink;

    public int getActiveId() {
        return activeId;
    }

    public void setupRender()
    {
        // I try to set some class attribute here but I find no matching function in myLink
        // myLink.setCssStyle();
    }   

    public String getMyDynCss(int currentLinkId) {
        if (currentLinkId==activeId)
            return "active";
        else
            return "xxx";
    }
}
```

The page that includes the component ...

```
<html t:type="layout" title="Test" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    <p:app_navigation>
        <t:testLink activeId="1000"/>
    </p:app_navigation>
</html>
```

Maybe a silly newbie question but I have still problems to think in Tapestry way.
Every help or useful hint is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear from your code what the difference between currentLinkId en activeId is and where currentId comes from. I'm almost assuming you have some sort of Loop setup you are not sharing here. But given you can obtain these variables from the enclosing component, you are pretty much there in your commented out code, you just need to remove the argument from your `getMyDynCss()` method. Like so:

Java:

```
public class TestLink {

    @Property
    @Parameter(required=true)
    private int activeId;

    @Property
    @Parameter(required=true)
    private int currentId;

    public String getMyDynCss() {
        if (currentId == activeId) {
            return "active";
        }
        else {
            return "xxx";
        }
    }
}
```

Your tml:

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <t:pagelink page="mytest" t:id="myLink" class="${myDynCss}">
</html>
```

Your enclosing component:

```
<html t:type="layout" title="Test" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    <p:app_navigation>
        <t:testLink activeId="1000" currentId="somePropertyFromSomewhere"/>
    </p:app_navigation>
</html>
```

Comment: And it is better to use prop: binding instead of ${...}, e.g. class="prop:myDynCss", http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-dontUseSyntax

Comment: @sody I think you are incorrect on the prop: binding here. This is true for defined parameter bindings on components, not so for simply printing a value into a DOM attribute like class.

Comment: @joostschouten sorry for the late response ... and thanx for solution. I will try it out. In the meantime  a found another way with afterRender event.

Comment: @joostschouten it seems to me your solutions will work only with one link in my TestLink component. Normally I got more as one. In this case I could subclass pagelink but this is another class more again :-D

Comment: @OkieOth I think you are making it more complex than needed. The trick is to make your method passing the value into currentId to be aware which link you are dealing with if within a loop or to use different methods to fetch the data from. Your problem does not lie with the components but with how you pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution use the the life cycle events. If there is any link that has a id that represents the active id (by convention) mark it as active.

My final component template ...

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <!-- convention: id == 'm' + numeric value for active entry --> 
    <t:pagelink page="mytest" id="m1000">
        I'm active
    </t:pagelink>

    <t:pagelink page="mytest2" id="m1001">
        I'm not active
    </t:pagelink>
</html>
```

The java code of the component ...

```
public class TestLink {
    @Parameter(required=true)
    private int activeId;

    // ... looking for a link with the active id ...
    void afterRender(final MarkupWriter writer) {
        // works only if the id follows the right convention :-D
        String activeElemId="m"+activeId; // <--
        Element activeLink=writer.getDocument().getElementById(activeElemId);
        if (activeLink!=null)
            activeLink.addClassName("active");
    }    
}
```

The code that includes the component ...

```
<html t:type="layout" title="Test" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    <p:app_navigation>
        <t:testLink activeId="1000"/>
    </p:app_navigation>
</html>
```